# Permission denied when attempting to upload file with PHP

Tags: php, file, permissions, upload, chmod

I have a problem uploading files with `move_uploaded_file(src, dest)`.
Uploadify is used to call the `upload.php` script which is executing:

```
move_uploaded_file($tempFile, $targetFile);
```

Every time I upload a file the permission on the ftp server is set to 363.
I tried to set the permission of the file with:

```
chmod($targetFile, 755);
```

But this didn't change anything. What can I do to make this function work correctly?

Also I can't delete the files from my ftp server, because I get a "permission denied".
How to delete them?

Comment: Unless you need those files to be executable, `0644` is sufficient.

Comment: do you have write permission to the destination directory ?

Comment: yes i do. how could i remove those files from my server with a ftp client which are set to 363 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use an octal value such as `0755`.

However, use `0644` instead since you most likely do not need/want the x-bit set on those files. If you cannot delete them via ftp, try `0664` or even `0666` - in shared hosting environments your php scripts usually run as the webserver user and your ftp account uses a different user.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this. I have a similar problem, this was the solution. +1